# How to save array of values in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to save array of values in django rest framework ,can you help to solve this problem.

example:

```
{
 "user":test{
              "category":cat1,
              "subcategories":sub1
            },
            {
              "category":cat2,
              "subcategories":sub2
            }
}
```

models.py

```
class SavingCategoryandPreferences(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
subcategories= models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='sub', default=1)
sort_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='subcategories_id', separator='', editable=True)
created_time = models.DateTimeField("Created Date", auto_now_add=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class SavecatsubSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = SavingCategoryandPreferences
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'category', 'subcategories')
```

views.py

```
class Mobilesavecatsub(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = serializers.SavecatsubSerialize
  queryset = SavingCategoryandPreferences.objects.all()
```

Comment: What does _save_ mean, exactly? Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this problem:

1. If you're just saving the data and do not want to process it in your application, the simplest method is just stringifying the dictionary (`json.dumps` is a good option) and saving the string as a `TextField` with a large max_length. Not recommended if you want to query results from the stringified dictionary.
2. If you want to query the saved data, the ideal way is to create multiple models for your internal fields and link them via a `ForeignKey` to your base model. Example:

   ```
   class User(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   class Category (models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)

   class Subcategory (models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
   ```